# Is there a way to stop couchdb indexer process?

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

Is there any way to halt the couchdb futon processing Indexer? I find it difficult and too long to wait when there is huge datas in the views. Any comment is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not through Futon. You need to kill *couchjs* process that handled view indexation: most probably it will be highlighted by high CPU usage counter, but `killall couchjs` works too.